# @Bean and @Qualifier apparently not working

Tags: java, spring

I have a scenario in which I consume from two different Kinesis streams in two separate AWS accounts. Therefore, using KCL, I'm creating two schedulers with different Kinesis/Dynamo/Cloudwatch beans. I'm trying to assign each bean to its corresponding scheduler using @Bean and @Qualifier. But so far it has not worked and I'm not sure why.

These is one of my beans:

```
@Bean(name = "localStreamsKinesisClient")
public KinesisAsyncClient localStreamsKinesisClient() {

    final NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder asyncHttpClientBuilder = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
            .maxConcurrency(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .http2Configuration(Http2Configuration.builder()
                    .initialWindowSize(INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE_BYTES)
                    .healthCheckPingPeriod(Duration.ofMillis(HEALTH_CHECK_PING_PERIOD_MILLIS)).build())
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP2)
            .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300));

    return KinesisAsyncClient.builder()
            .region(Region.of(awsRegion))
            .httpClientBuilder(asyncHttpClientBuilder)
            .credentialsProvider(fileCredentialsProvider)
            .build();
}
```

I have also already tried annotating with:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("")

@Bean
public KinesisAsyncClient nameOfMyBean () {}

@Bean("")
```

And this is where I want to qualify the bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("localStreamsKinesisClient")
private KinesisAsyncClient localStreamsKinesisClient;
```

My latest attempt was this one, using @Autowired. I have also already tried:

```
@Qualifier("localStreamsKinesisClient")
private final KinesisAsyncClient localStreamsKinesisClient;


private final @Qualifier("localStreamsKinesisClient") KinesisAsyncClient localStreamsKinesisClient;
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in com.allpago.docgen.configuration.KclConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - localStreamsKinesisClient: defined by method 'localStreamsKinesisClient' in class path resource [com/allpago/docgen/configuration/AwsConfig.class]
    - crossAccountStreamsKinesisClient: defined by method 'crossAccountStreamsKinesisClient' in class path resource [com/allpago/docgen/configuration/AwsConfig.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

At some point I noticed that maybe the beans were not being properly scanned, so I added this annotation to the file in which I try to qualify the bean:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.allpago.docgen.configuration" })
```

Both files are in the same package. What is wrong here? It seems like it should work, I tried several possibilities, and I think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Maybe need more info (the KclConfig class). Seems that scan works because Spring detects the two KinesisAsyncClient beans. The problem is what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a missing configuration in Lombok, which I'm using to generate the constructors. For me, creating this file solved the problem:

lombok.config

```
# see https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/745
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
```

The annotations:

Aws config:

```
@Bean(name = "localStreamsKinesisClient")
public KinesisAsyncClient localStreamsKinesisClient() {}
```

Kcl config:

```
@Qualifier("localStreamsKinesisClient") private final KinesisAsyncClient localStreamsKinesisClient;
```

I also kept the `@ComponentScan` annotation in the KclConfig class, pointing to the package in which both these classes are in.

PS: I got the lead from another SO answer, which I lost the link for. If I find it I'll give credit.